# How to test if a blob was deleted in App Engine SDK 1.7.0 (Java)?

Tags: google-app-engine, blob

After updating the App Engine SDK to 1.7.0 some of our unit test started to fail.

In SDK 1.6.x I asserted that a blob was deleted like this:

```
    try {
        fileService.getBlobFile(blobKey);
        Assert.fail("Blob not deleted: " + blobKey);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException expected) {
        // OK
    }
```

In SDK 1.7.0 getBlobFile() is not throwing FileNotFoundException anymore.

I tried to provoke an exception, but it did not work out (no exception is thrown):

```
    try {
        AppEngineFile blobFile = fileService.getBlobFile(blobKey);
        boolean readable = blobFile.isReadable();
        FileReadChannel channel = fileService.openReadChannel(blobFile, false);
        channel.position(1);
        try {
            channel.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Silent
        }
        Assert.fail("Blob not deleted: " + blobKey);
    } catch (Exception expected) {
        // OK
    }
```

The blob should be deleted, but it's possible to open a channel for it...

So, any ideas how to check deletion was successful in unit testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using blobstoreService.fetchData to retrieve the first byte of the file.

It will throw if the file does not exist.

Comment: Maybe I found a loosely related bug in the SDK: For some strange reason, deleting a blob after blobstoreService.fetchData always fails in my test. In contrast, deleting the blob after getting the data with fileService.openReadChannel works fine.

Here's the exception:
java.io.IOException: Could not delete: .\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\feopHbOletLHZ7BzBqXMqQ
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.FileBlobStorage.deleteBlob(FileBlobStorage.java:44)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.LocalBlobstoreService$1.run(LocalBlobstoreService.java:128)

Comment: Can you open an issue in the tracker?

Answer (score 0):

App Engine does not yet support JDK 1.7.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough: the issue about the new App Engine SDK 1.7.0, not Java 7. Edited the question, hope it improved.